# How to acces custom input value from checkout form in opencart

Tags: opencart, checkout

How can I access custom input value from the checkout shipping method section and use it in `catalog\model\shipping\flat.php`?

So far in `catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\checkout.tpl` I’ve changed:

```
data: $('#shipping-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #shipping-method textarea'),
```

to:

```
data: $('#shipping-method input[type=\'hidden\'], #shipping-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #shipping-method textarea'),
```

So now I guess the custom value is posted via Ajax but how to access it in `flat.php` mentioned above?

In `catalog\controller\checkout\shipping.php` after

```
$this->session->data['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_methods'][$shipping[0]]['quote'][$shipping[1]];
```

I've added

```
$custom = $this->session->data['custom'];
```

but don’t know where to go from there so that `$custom` variable will be available in `flat.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to **StackOverflow**!

I guess that `$this->session->data['custom']` would return null and generate an `Undefined index` notice as You didn't set any value for this index anywhere (or You just didn't post the code?).

In `shipping.php`, instead of Your line

```
$custom = $this->session->data['custom'];
```

do

```
$this->session->data['custom_value'] = $this->request->post['shipping_method']['custom'];
```

(I suppose the hidden field has name `custom` and is sent via AJAX as `shipping_method` array)

Now that we have set the value to the session, in Your **`flat.php`** You can do

```
$custom = $this->session->data['custom_value'];
```

and now You have the custom hidden value present also in `flat.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply shadyyx, as you suspect I didn't post the code, there is indeed a hidden input named 'custom' and it does have a value. Now, not sure whether you wrote 'custom_value' intentionally or you just meant 'custom'; anyway I tried both ways and it won't let me proceed with the checkout, while with my lame line it would, so there's gotta be something.

Comment: Looks like I'm trying to add salt to the soup that's already been eaten. Let me explain: shipping.php takes care of (1)gathering info about available shipping methods (that would be flat too), and (2)displaying them in the checkout form, where (3)hidden input value gets set. So it's too late. Or is it? If the same shipping.php collects the info of the shipping method customer chose ... maybe I could change my flat.php data right there?

Comment: must have been doing something wrong 'cause now turns out everything's fine with your code, I just put ['custom'] instead of ['custom_value']. Although I can't use it in flat.php for it looks like by the time I set my custom value to the session flat.php has already been used, but I can and did use it elsewhere to get exactly what I need. Wouldn't have done it without your help though, so big thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow won't let me upvote your answer :(, says I need reputation 15

Comment: @user2463644 You are welcome! It doesn't matter - You can accept the answer (by clicking on the tick on the right to my answer) and then upvote once You earn enough of reputation ;-) Don't hesitate to come back should You encounter another problem(s).